# PlayOnLinux Steam black screen

Tags: 16.04, wine, steam, playonlinux

Only the steam library and friend list works. I can install games and play them.

Anything else (Store, community, profile, etc)  shows a **black screen** instead of the page.

Steam library:

[image: steam screenshot]

Black screen:

[image: empty screen]

Comment: Please [edit] this post to provide further detail. The phrases "Anything else" and "work(s)" are quite vague. Thank you for helping us help you! You will likely find https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask useful..

Comment: As unclear? I'm asking for a fix. I can just install and play games, tools etc. Everything that is in the "Library" Tab. Everything else will result in a black screen as shown in the pictures edit. For example going to "featured" in the Store tab will show a black screen or "discussions" on the community tab or "inventory" on the user name tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common problem with Wine/Steam. I encountered it and here's what I did to make it work. Make sure to have your wine compatibility set to Windows XP for Steam while running the exe with the "-no-cef-sandbox" argument.

Example : "wine Steam.exe -no-cef-sandbox"

This can be done in PlayOnLinux by following these steps:

1. Highlight the program you wish to run and click configure (Steam in this case (I just renamed it to Steamwine when installing it))
   [image: PlayOnLinux with Configure Highlighted]
2. Now enter "-no-cef-sandbox" into the arguments box.
   [image: PlayOnLinux with the Arguments box highlighted]
   It should look like the box below when you are done: 
   [image: PlayOnLinux with -no-cef-sandbox in Arguments box]
3. Now go over to the Wine tab and click "Configure Wine"
   [image: PlayOnLinux Wine Tab with Configure Wine Selected]
   And make sure the "Windows Version" is set to "Windows XP"
   [image: Windows Version in winecfg set to Windows XP]
4. Now click okay once Windows XP is the Windows Version that is set, and close out the PlayOnLinux Configuration window. You may need to quit PlayOnLinux for changes to apply.

Sources:
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=28640
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-15371.html 
https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29066
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444

Comment: Where did you obtain the idea to launch Steam with the -no-cef-sandbox switch? I can't find it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to sleep. It is mentioned that you must use the "-no-cef-sandbox" argument on the wine database. I shall now edit my comment to explain. I have tested this as well on Ubuntu 17.10 running PlayOnLinux and Steam renamed to "Steamwine" in this case.

Comment: For some reason when I press configure it does nothing. Linux bugs I guess.

Comment: How did you install PlayOnLinux?

Comment: Through the terminal I recall.

Comment: Just so you know, the playonlinux package for 14.04 is outdated. It seems as if 17.04 and 17.10 are the only ones that are up to date.

Comment: Forget all that. It worked! Had to re-install Steam Wine. Now to get everyone removing downvotes..

Comment: This is no longer a viable path, steam does not support XP.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
(I use cinnamon desktop with software rendering => Windows like desktop)
I solved it like that:

1. Configured the Steam app in playonlinux to use Windows 10.
2. Use the steam icon in the taskbar to launch one of your games that needs to be installed.
   [Steam menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PifyA.png)

Steam will open the download screen where you can choose your installation folder and so on ...

[Steam Game Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdCJh.png)

You'll be able to start the game after that if it's compatible with (the used) wine (version).

I hope it helps ;)

## Updated information

After some testing I came to the conclusion it's far better to install Steam for Linux.
You can setup your games to compatibility mode.
The best way to do so for compatibility with the most recent games, is to download:
https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/tag/6.1-GE-2
Unpack it and follow the instructions describe on the bottom of this page:
https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom

Except that you put the unpacked Proton-6.1-GE-2 in the created folder.
I also overwrited the content of Proton-6.1-GE (Release 2 wasn't yet out released 2 days ago), with those from proton-ge-custom, in order to be able to run Baldur's Gate 3. You'll probably don't have to do it with this last release.

You will not have any problems with your Steam menu's after that, and most of your "Only for Windows Games" will run smootly on Ubuntu !

That is my case for all my Steam Library ;)

Cheers !!!