# Playonlinux Steam Black Screen -- update

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux, 22.04

I got black screen like said in this post :
[PlayOnLinux Steam black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997568/playonlinux-steam-black-screen)

Friend's list, Library, everything show me a black screen.

The answer in the link i posted can't work anymore : a part of this answer is to put **Windows Version : Windows XP** in wineconfig

As of now, steam can't be launched with Windows XP.
So I have to put Windows 7 or 10, and the **"-no-cef-sandbox"**  argument seems to be useless alone.

I can add that i also tried to put **d3d11** in **Native Windows** without success.
Someone could help ?

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same issue. I found an easy fix for me:

Instead of putting the "no cef sandbox..." in the Arguments field, just type:

```
wine steam.exe -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist
```

That did the trick for me! Hope it works for you too.

Comment: this works for me. Just adding -no-browser instead of -no-cef-sandbox did the job also. But with this way i can't open friend's list.

Comment: This is not a fix or even necessary, you could always just go to the View menu and select the mini list regardless of launch parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that works for me:

```
wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist
```

Comment: This isn't necessary, you could always just go to the View menu and select the mini list even when steam opens to a blank page

Answer (score 0):

After an upgrade of 20.04 to 22.04, the steam launchpad icon opened only black windows.  Starting steam from the command line still worked. The fix was to
edit the /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop file:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

and edit the steam.desktop file:

```
sudo vi steam.desktop
```

and change the line in the [Desktop Entry] section to false:
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false

My preferred GPU was the Nvidia GPU, so when the entry was true, the Intel
GPU was used (and didn't work for steam).