# Steam PlayOnLinux launches to black screen

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

When I try to run Steam from PlayOnLinux (Wine) it launches to a black screen.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have no arguments being used in configuration:

[image]

and when I add `-no-browser` per this [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185938/playonlinux-steam-black-screen-update).

[image]

I still get a black screen, but also this error:

[image]

How can I launch steam with Wine and get past the black screen?

Comment: Are you trying to run the Steam client itself? Steam has a native Linux client and Steam is in Ubuntu repositories.    Why would you want to run the Windows version through emulation and compatibility layers?

Comment: Please start with your OS/product/release details.  Those details allow us to picture your software stack easily (*along with any bug reports/issues we've seen for that release*)

Comment: @Nmath Years ago many people did that in order to run (Windows) Steam games. But now with the wine based Steam's Proton being available in the Linux client this "hack" is just ridiculous.

Comment: @Nmath I am trying to play steam games that aren't available on linux, and this was the only method I found online.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Proton worked great, using these instructions: https://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/install_proton_ge_ubuntu_linux_steam
Thank you!

Comment: Great, but there's no need to do a separated installation. It can be enabled in the Steam client.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). There isn't a "one size fits all" solution to running Windows software in Ubuntu. If you are hoping this method will do that, unfortunately it doesn't exist.   You need to research each individual application independently. This means you also need to ask about each specific application you are having problems with separately and include the details about that single application. Always ask about the actual root problem you are having, not problems implementing a solution you think might work

Comment: If you have a solution, please add the details of your solution as an answer, not a comment. Link only answers are considered "very low quality". Essential details of your answer should be enumerated in your answer. Links should be used for reference or citation only. Our entire purpose on Ask Ubuntu is to create a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu. We are not a forum or help desk. We delete questions that are not likely to be helpful for future visitors. Thanks for contributing. https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
This question has been solved for the OP in the comments by a better way.

Anecdotally, there are sometimes differences between the (recommended) approach of Linux_Steam>Wine>Game and the (non-recommended) approach of Wine>Windows_Steam>Game. I suspect these differences -could- be overcome by working harder to configure things correctly inside Linux_Steam, and that this is largely about the convenience of which default settings end up being automatically applied.

I personally can't get my PlayOnLinux to install SteamSetup.exe on a virtual drive at the moment, but the following solution might be helpful to others in the OP's position, given it was already adopting a non-recommended approach.

Given how complex Steam is, Windows_Steam works incredibly well in Wine, so the OP might want to try creating a 32-bit Wine instance and installing SteamSetup.exe there - which takes out PlayOnLinux. I think that reducing the complexity is still virtuous when we are doing something non-recommended.

On my PC this would look like downloading SteamSetup.exe to some folder, then opening a terminal there and running the command:-

$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine SteamSetup.exe

(But don't paste this into Terminal before knowing the right location of your wine Prefix and making sure that 32-bit not 64-bit is desired)

In that command, ~/.wine32 is where in the past I have asked wine to put my 32-bit wine prefix. On my PC, Windows_Steam is installed at ~/.wine32/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/ (btw I suppose that ~/.wine32 is a "prefix" and ~/.wine32/drive_c/ is a "virtual drive", and so a wine prefix is analogous to a Windows PC's 'My Computer' folder.)

When following this approach, 32-bit and 64-bit versions of wine have to be installed to separate wine prefixes, which from Steam's perspective are then counted as separate PCs for their user authentication.

Also, I've always found this to be problem-free but it might be wise to give Steam its own wine prefixes - in case it breaks them. I've trusted that the Prefix should be safe from errors inside Steam; Wine should be safe from anything that goes wrong inside a Prefix; and the Linux system should be safe from anything that goes wrong inside Wine - but if some bug or exploit in Windows Steam arises, those presumptions are all at our own risk. Of course often Steam accounts are valuable and linked to Paypal accounts.

For creating the wine prefix in the first place, there are lots of places to find instructions, e.g. https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/create-wine-prefixes-on-linux/

In practice, PlayOnLinux is sometimes only automating this and providing a GUI. I find that often when something (e.g. winetricks or installing some Windows requisites) doesn't work as expected in POL, I can also try navigating to POL's virtual drive and using Wine commands in the terminal.

On my Windows_Steam, I do not get the same error as the OP has in PlayonLinux, but much of the display is a black screen and unless I change it to "Small Mode" within the Steam settings.

I think what I've suggested here counts as a solution because it would give the OP the same functionality as they would have if they ran Steam via PlayOnLinux. It bears repeating again that the recommended approach is to start with the Linux version of Steam. But I haven't personally experienced any negative side-effects from approaching it backwards, and feel it has sometimes been a quicker way to get certain games running. And as a project, it perhaps gets us using some Wine commands directly without relying on PlayOnLinux's UI, and seeing how Steam puts the games it installs this way in analogous places to a native Windows install.